# Alinear dentro de nav Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Estoy intentando alinear un botón a la derecha dentro de mi nav y no lo consigo.

```html
  

  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
       Cabecera
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
       <div id="principal">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
          
          <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom  navbar-dark bg-dark">
           <button type="button" id="addParte" class="btn btn-outline-success float-right "><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Parte</button>
          </nav>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Alinear cómo, o dónde?

Comment: He editado la pregunta, La alineación es  en este caso a la derecha. Gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esta nav va a tener algo más que el botón, como por ejemplo una lista de items? Porque si solo vas a poner el botón creo que es mejor hacerlo en un div y no en una nav.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Cabecera
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div id="principal">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <!--div en lugar de nav-->
            <div class="fixed-bottom bg-dark text-right py-2">
              <button type="button" id="addParte" class="btn btn-outline-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Parte</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Para alinear elementos a la derecha dentro de un `navbar`, Bootstrap cuenta con la clase `.ml-auto` que se aplica a las listas `<ul>`, esto es posible [si se usa Flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#auto-margins).

Lo que hace esta clase es "empujar" los elementos hacia la derecha asignando un margen automático a la izquierda.

La clase `.float-right` no te funciona porque entra en conflicto con los elementos en Flex del `navbar`, la propia Bootstrap [te recomienda tener cuidado con ello](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/float/#overview).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Cabecera
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div id="principal">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">

            <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom  navbar-dark bg-dark">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li>
                  <button type="button" id="addParte" class="btn btn-outline-success float-right"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Parte</button></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```